# How to build two variants in a gradle task

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, build-variant

I have 3 build variants, say debug, staging and release
I want to generate different combinations of build like staging and release build
or debug and release build. 
I believe writing a gradle task would help. Can anyone help write this task.

Comment: what have you tried so far? have you looked at ? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cant merge your build type resources. But with a new concept of "gradle dimensions" you can merge flavors resources and source sets. Here is an exapmle https://stackoverflow.com/a/49403213/6193843